# CSS Gurus, Beginner needs a bit help: Can't center middle column on 3-col layout

Tags: css

Beginner to HTML here.

I am at my wit's end and yet I can't get this working. Could you please have a look?

What I want is to push the text inside navleft to the leftmost side of hte viewport, center the contents of navcenter and push the contents of navright to the rightmost side of the viewport.

Whatever I do, the width of navcenter is only its contents, it doesnt fill the area between navleft and navright. I tried 1 million CSS 3-column options to no avail (negative margin, padding, etc).

I can't get rid of wrapper because it is used for sticyk footer (i left out the irrelevant code, body entries, etc.).

What can i do?

Maria

PS: Yes I know my CSS sucks, and it would look like a big mess to you, please excuse and  bear with me. Thank you very much for your time.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en"> 

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>title</title>
<link href="2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />


</head>
<body>

<div class="wrapper">
<div id="headerMain">
<div id="header">


<div class="headerLogoLeft"></div>
<div class="headerLogoCenter"></div>


<div id="nav">
<div id="navleft">navleft</div>
<div id="navcenter">center</div>
<div id="navright">navright</div>
</div>


</div> 
</div>
</div> 


</body>
</html>




/* CSS Document */

* { margin:0; padding:0; border:0; }


html {
 height:100%;
 width:100%;
}

.wrapper {
 min-height:100%;
 height:auto !important;
 margin:0 auto -26px;
 background:#e9e9e9; 
}

body{
 font: normal 12px/16px Arial, Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 height: 100%;
 min-width:1024px;
 width:100%;
 border: 0px;
 background-color:#CFCFCF;
}


#headerMain{
 width:100%;
 background:url(img/header_bg.png) 0 0 repeat-x;
 color:#D2C7A3;
}

#header{
 width:100%;
 background:url(img/header_bg_top.png) 0 0 repeat-x;
 margin:0;
 height:153px;
}


.headerLogoLeft {
  height:84px;
  width:34%;
  float:left;
  text-align:left;
}

.headerLogoLeft img  {
  height:72px;
  width:72px;
  display:inline;
  padding-top:5px;
}


.headerLogoCenter {
  height:84px;
  width:66%;
  float:left;
  text-align:left;
}

.headerLogoCenter img  {
  height:84px;
  width:550px;
  display:inline;
}



#nav {
 width:100%;
 height:33px;
 color: #9E9E9E;
 line-height:33px;
 font-size:13px;

}


#navleft {
 height:33px;
 float:left;
 width:200px;
 text-align:left;
}


#navcenter {
 height:33px;
 line-height:33px;
 text-align:right;
 float:left;


}

#navright {
 height:33px;
 width:200px;
 text-align:right;
  float: right;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you can leave ie6 support out, which you should.. then this will work:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title></title>

<style>
/* CSS Document */

* { margin:0; padding:0; }


html {
 height:100%;
 width:100%;
}

.wrapper {
 min-height:100%;
 height:auto !important;
 margin:0 auto -26px;
 background:#e9e9e9; 
}

body{
 font: normal 12px/16px Arial, Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 height: 100%;
 min-width:1024px;
 width:100%;
 border: 0px;
 background-color:#CFCFCF;
}


#headerMain{
 width:100%;
 background:url(img/header_bg.png) 0 0 repeat-x;
 color:#D2C7A3;
}

#header{
 width:100%;
 background:url(img/header_bg_top.png) 0 0 repeat-x;
 margin:0;
 height:153px;
}


.headerLogoLeft {
  height:84px;
  width:34%;
  float:left;
  text-align:left;
}

.headerLogoLeft img  {
  height:72px;
  width:72px;
  display:inline;
  padding-top:5px;
}


.headerLogoCenter {
  height:84px;
  width:66%;
  float:left;
  text-align:left;
}

.headerLogoCenter img  {
  height:84px;
  width:550px;
  display:inline;
}



#nav {
 width:100%;
 height:33px;
 color: #9E9E9E;
 line-height:33px;
 font-size:13px;
 position:relative;
}


#navleft {
 height:33px;
 float:left;
 width:200px;
 text-align:left;
 position:absolute;
 left:0; top:0;
 z-index:20;
 background:lightgreen;
}


#navcenter {
 height:33px;
 line-height:33px;
 text-align:center;
 position:absolute;
 left:0;right:0;top:0;
 padding-left:200px;
 padding-right:200px;
 z-index:10;
 background:yellow;
}

#navright {
 height:33px;
 width:200px;
 text-align:right;
 position:absolute;
 right:0;top:0;
 z-index:20;
 background:lightblue;
}
</style>

</head>

<body>


<div class="wrapper">
    <div id="headerMain">
        <div id="header">

            <div class="headerLogoLeft"></div>
            <div class="headerLogoCenter"></div>


            <div id="nav">
                <div id="navleft">navleft</div>
                <div id="navcenter">center</div>
                <div id="navright">navright</div>
            </div>


        </div> 
    </div>
</div> 





</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I had one <div class="spacer"></div> right after <div class="headerLogoCenter"></div>. Is this what is pushing the nav bar to where it is (which is fine, right after logos)? Removing spacer moves it to the top of the page. Can I also use absolute for haderLogoLeft and HeaderLogoCenter above?

Comment: yes you can use absolute positioning for the header divs also.

in your code I think the problem was the last right div floated right. floating something to the right is ok, but that div should be first in the html source followed by the other float left and non floated elements

Comment: Very right! Putting right float first and adding width:100%;
margin-left:-200px; margin-right:-200px; to center column fixed the problem. I will read up on absolute positioning. I really appreciate this help. I cant upvote yet, but when i collect enough reputation, i will come and upvote it. You have a great day!

Comment: no worries maria. read up on positioning here: http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/

also you can still accept my answer without voting up can't you?